# Why to declare a String (as final) and then use it?

Tags: java, programming-practices, variables, final

In a typical spring mvc validator class, while inserting an errorCode value in the Errors object, what difference does it make between using a String (`props.somefield.req`) like so

```
errors.rejectValue("elementId", "props.somefield.req");
```

verses a declared static final String ?

```
private static final String SOMFIELD_REQ = "props.somefield.req"; ...
errors.rejectValue("elementId", SOMFIELD_REQ);
```

Does it improve the performance even in a slightest way? I have read a few questions on stack overflow ([String and final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874978/string-and-final), [Does it make sense to define a final String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233309/does-it-make-sense-to-define-a-final-string-in-java)) but no one got around to answering [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677670/when-exactly-are-we-supposed-to-use-public-static-final-string) update question.

Comment: meta bit: the reason that no one ever answered it was that extensions to existing questions really don't make for good questions.  Things like 'Update' and 'Edit' are signs of a [creeping question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143764/handling-creeping-questions) (what if the creeping question is a dup? or if someone answers the update but not the original? or the original but not the update? - followup questions in new questions is the best policy)

Comment: Every read-only string that is used more than once can savely be put into a static final field, if only to avoid mis-typing errors or to be able to refactor. For literals that are only used once I think it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At runtime, it does not make a difference.

The point is readability - as a member variable, it likely is declared at the beginning of the class' source code, and making it static means it doesn't have to be allocated for each new instance of the class.

Making it final signifies to the reader that the value will not change (to the compiler too, but that's less important here).

This way, there are no "magic values" buried in the implementation, and if a change is desired to the "constant", it only needs to be changed in one place.

This basically mimics what a C programmer would do with a #define.

Comment: +1 the performance gain is irrelevant, it is all about readability, maintainability and intent.

Answer (score 5):

### `final` fields have many benefits!

Declaring fields as `final` has valuable documentation benefits for developers who want to use or extend your class - not only does it help explain how the class works, but it enlists the compiler's help in enforcing your design decisions. Unlike with `final` methods, **declaring a final field helps the optimizer make better optimization decisions**, because if the compiler knows the field's value will not change, **it can safely cache the value in a register**. `final` fields also provide an extra level of safety by having the compiler enforce that a field is read-only.

Don't try to use `final` as a performance management tool. There are much better, less constraining ways to enhance your program's performance. Use `final` where it reflects the fundamental semantics of your program: to indicate that classes are intended to be immutable or that fields are intended to be read-only.

Before declare final fields, you should ask yourself: *does this field really need to be mutable?*